# How to create library with classes that extends sdk?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Let's say I have class

```
public class Point extends Point2D.Double{ // Point2D is of course from sdk

public void myMethod(){}
    //some actions
}
```

The problem is when I include this code as a library from .jar file to my another project I only have access to myMethod() and not to any fields and methods from Point2D.Double class.

to give example:

```
import com.mylibrary.Point

public class SomeClass{
     public SomeClass(){
     Point myPoint = new Point(1,2);

     myPoint.myMethod(); // ok
     myPoint.getX(); // not ok althought there is getX() method in Point2D.Double class
     }
}
```

How can I get access to both compiled codes?

Comment: [This actually works fine for me.](http://ideone.com/Hs7Y7L)

Comment: Provide more details and/or code. It's completely unclear what is the cause of your problem.

Comment: I've edited my post, hope the issue is clear now.

Comment: @MaciejF If you read carefully the code in your update, at line 5 you are doing `Point myPoint =` **`new Point(1,2);`**, which is calling a constructor that you didn't define, and that belongs to the `Point2D.Double` class. Are you sure that you tested this? My first example shows that your code works

Comment: In your example code is within same .java file. I want to use it as a compiled class files by import. And yes I should write a constructor matching superclass constructor but that's not the point of my problem.

Comment: @MaciejF I can't reproduce your issue. If you try it yourself it will compile, I just tested. Are you sure that you are importing the right `Point`?

Comment: @MaciejF With my second comment I was trying to tell you that the constructor you are calling belongs to `Point2D.Double`. This demonstrates that you have access to methods defined in the `Point2D.Double` class. If you have access to the `Double(double x, double y)` constructor, you will also have access to the `getX()` method.

Comment: @MaciejF Can you please share a screenshot of the compilation issue?

Comment: @BackSlash At this point - yes I have access to all methods but not when I export it to a .jar file and include it as a library to another project. After that I have only access to my code.

Comment: @MaciejF Could you share a screenshot/something that demostrates the issue? Actually, it's pretty weird, maybe I'm wrong, maybe this is a bug of the JVM, I can't tell you what it is without having a complete working example that shows what's going on